# How to translate an image in python PIL?

Tags: python, windows, image-processing, python-imaging-library

My intention is to do as shown below:

http://postimg.org/image/pdb6urf1d/

My function:

```
def translacao(imagem1):

  imagem1.save("translate.png")
  destino = Image.open("translate.png")
  destino = destino.resize((400,400))
  #Tamanho Imagem - Largura e Altura
  width = destino.size[0]
  height = destino.size[1]
  x_loc = 20
  y_loc = 20
  x_loc = int(x_loc)
  y_loc = int(y_loc)
  imagem1.convert("RGB")
  destino.convert("RGB")

  for y in range(0, height):

     for x in range(0, width):

       xy = (x, y)     
       red, green, blue = destino.getpixel(xy)    
       x += x_loc    
       y += y_loc    
       destino.putpixel((x, y), (red, green, blue))

  return destino.save("translate.png")
```

This error appears:

```
 C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Mikhail/PycharmProjects/SistMult/histograma.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Mikhail/PycharmProjects/SistMult/histograma.py", line 289, in <module>
 translacao(imagem1)
 File "C:/Users/Mikhail/PycharmProjects/SistMult/histograma.py", line 262, in translacao destino.putpixel((x, y), (red, green, blue))
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1269, in putpixel
 return self.im.putpixel(xy, value)
 IndexError: image index out of range
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating on x and y but changing it inside each iteration:

for y in range(0, height):

```
 for x in range(0, width):

   xy = (x, y)     
   red, green, blue = destino.getpixel(xy)    
   x += x_loc    #this changes the value of x
   y += y_loc    #this changes the value of y

   #at this point x can be outside of 0..height-1 and y can be outside of 0..width-1
   destino.putpixel((x, y), (red, green, blue))
```

you could try iterating:

```
 for y in range(0,height-yloc):
     for x in range(0,height-xloc):
        xy = (x, y)     
        red, green, blue = destino.getpixel(xy)    
        x += x_loc  
        y += y_loc  
        #at this point x can be outside of 0..height-1 and y can be outside of 0..width-1
        destino.putpixel((x, y), (red, green, blue))
```

BTW range(0,a) can be written as range(a)

Also, these two commands aren't doing anything because you're not assigning it to any varible:

```
imagem1.convert("RGB")
destino.convert("RGB")
```

Comment: The problem is that x and y are being translated and after translation fall outside the image.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague managed to solve the problem . Solution below :

```
 destino = Image.open("foto.png")
    #Tamanho Imagem - Largura e Altura
    lar = destino.size[0]
    alt = destino.size[1]
    x_loc = 200
    y_loc = 200
    imagem_original = np.asarray(destino.convert('RGB'))
    for x in range(lar):
        for y in range(alt):
            if x >= x_loc and y >= y_loc:
               yo = x - x_loc
               xo = y - y_loc
               destino.putpixel((x,y), (imagem_original[xo,yo][0],imagem_original[xo,yo][1],imagem_original[xo,yo][2]))
            else:
               destino.putpixel((x,y), (255, 255, 255, 255))
    destino.save("translate.png")
```